# Comparing a value to a NULL in t-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, null

I was curious if it's legal in t-SQL to compare a NULL to a value?

For instance, if I have:

```
WITH ctx AS(SELECT 123 AS n0, NULL AS n1)
SELECT n0 FROM ctx
WHERE ctx.n1 < 130
```

the WHERE clause in that case is always evaluated as FALSE. Is it something I can rely on?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't compare NULL with any other value, it will result in `'UNKNOWN'`.

From [msdn source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191504%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

> A value of NULL indicates that the value is unknown. A value of NULL
>   is different from an empty or zero value. No two null values are
>   equal. Comparisons between two null values, or between a NULL and any
>   other value, return unknown because the value of each NULL is unknown.

Answer (score 3):

All boolean operations in T-Sql with null value returns 'UNKNOWN', which is recognized as false in clauses. You can use ISNULL function when you want set some default value.
for example in your case:

```
WITH ctx AS(SELECT 123 AS n0, NULL AS n1)
SELECT n0 FROM ctx
WHERE isnull(ctx.n1,0) < 130
```

Comment: Yeah, also the check 'is null' works:

`WITH ctx AS(SELECT 123 AS n0, NULL AS n1)
SELECT n0 FROM ctx
WHERE ctx.n1 < 130 OR ctx.n1 is NULL`

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the value of ANSI_NULLS.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191270%28v=sql.90%29.aspx

> When SET ANSI_NULLS is ON, a comparison in which one or more of the
>   expressions is NULL does not yield either TRUE or FALSE; it yields
>   UNKNOWN.
>
> Transact-SQL supports an extension that allows for the comparison
>   operators to return TRUE or FALSE when comparing against null values.
>   This option is activated by setting ANSI_NULLS OFF. When ANSI_NULLS is
>   OFF, comparisons such as ColumnA = NULL return TRUE when ColumnA
>   contains a null value and FALSE when ColumnA contains some value
>   besides NULL.

Answer (score 0):

The WHERE clause in the following `=` is also FALSE. You need to be very careful with NULLs

```
WITH ctx AS
(
SELECT 123 AS n0, NULL AS n1
) 
SELECT *
FROM ctx 
WHERE ctx.n1 = NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

I've always used the EXISTS keyword along with EXCEPT like so

```
SELECT 1
WHERE EXISTS ((SELECT 1) EXCEPT (SELECT NULL))
```